# Group by column name and content type in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, content-type, list-view, modern-experience

I'm trying to refine our SharePoint List (Office 365). I have searched the Internet for answers but cannot find anything that is usable to me. I am not the tenancy level administrator just a local administrator for the sharepoint list.

I'm trying to group items by column name first and then content type as the second level group. Is this doable without SharePoint Designer and coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see content type as choice option under "Group By" section on list view settings (classic experience):

[image]

So, I tried to apply group by on content type column from modern experience list view & it worked for one level of grouping:

[image]

So, I saved this list view from modern experience & then opened classic experience list view setting and noticed that the grouping is not shown on settings page:

[image]

---

Also, when I tried to apply grouping on another column from modern/classic experience, grouping on content type column got removed.

So, I don't think it is possible to apply grouping on content type using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh! This is the conclusion I come to as well but wanted to check with you before I give up. Many thanks!